# Equivalent of the php fmod in C#

Tags: c#, php, geospatial

Does anybody know what the C# equivalent of fmod is?  I'm trying to convert this line of code to C#.

```
$lon_rad = fmod(($long1+$dlon_rad + M_PI), 2*M_PI) - M_PI;
```

Here's what I have so far.  I just need the fmod converted.

```
double lon_rad = ((lon1+dlon_rad + Math.PI), 2*Math.PI) - Math.PI;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other people have given the correct operator to use, but not the entire syntax, which would be:

```
double lon_rad = ((lon1+dlon_rad + Math.PI) % (2*Math.PI)) - Math.PI;
```

Comment: I would change the "2" to "2.0"

Comment: That's probably a good idea for optimization, but I'm sure that it would affect the results, as Math.PI is already a double.

Comment: True.  I knew PI was a double, but I can never remember which direction it will coerce the operands whenever they are of different types so I eliminate any doubt by clarifying the numeric literals.

Comment: It always makes them the larger of the two types.  It makes sense if you think about similar types.  For instance, if I multiply a byte by an int, the result will be an int because there are int values outside the byte range.

Answer (score 2):

Use a P/Invoked call into the standard library (from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20dckbeh%28VS.71%29.aspx)):

```
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]
static extern double fmod(double x, double y);
```

Comment: That works but I was hoping for a C# solution without having to import a DLL.

Comment: You will always have that dll.

Comment: CORRECTION: do not use this.  Use the built-in modulus operator, it works correctly for all numeric types.  Pinvoking to fmodf will add unnecessary overhead.

Comment: I changed the accepted answer to the one that uses the modulus operator.  Thanks all.

Comment: "You will always have `msvcrt.dll`". Anyone heard of Mono? Silverlight?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the % modulus operator?

Comment: @plinth: "fmod — Returns the floating point remainder (modulo) of the division of the arguments" -- PHP Manual

Comment: @plinth "The modulus operator (%) computes the remainder after dividing its first operand by its second." -- C# manual

Comment: fmod works on floating point numbers - the fmod(10.0, 3.1) is different from (double)((int)10.0 % (int)3.1).  "The fmod function calculates the floating-point remainder f of x / y such that x = i * y + f, where i is an integer, f has the same sign as x, and the absolute value of f is less than the absolute value of y."

Comment: @R. Bemrose, they're not the same. `fmod(5.7, 1.3)` gives `0.5`, while `5.7 % 1.3` gives `0`.

Comment: @Ionut G. Stan: `double test = 5.7 % 1.3; Console.WriteLine(test.ToString();` prints `0.5`

Comment: or rather, it would had I not omitted one of the paratheses (whoops)

Comment: Stan, you may have a casting issue.  Because of the way C# will coerce types during arithmetic, sometimes you have to explicitely cast them and/or specify the types of numeric literals.  Can you give a more complete code for how you tested "5.7 % 1.3 gives 0"

Comment: I stand corrected - msdn says that modulus is defined for all numeric types, and % for doubles *is* fmod.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double fmod(double dividend, double divisor )
{
    double Modulus = 
                     (Math.Abs(dividend) - (Math.Abs(divisor) * 
                     (Math.Floor(Math.Abs(dividend) / Math.Abs(divisor))))) * 
                     Math.Sign(dividend);

    return Modulus;
}
```

Comment: Add a description to your answer, Just a code block wont help much.